# Where to find cordova-pdf-generator global pdf variable?

Tags: cordova, pdf, generator

I am trying to use this pluging:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordovan-pdf-generator.

I have trouble figuring out where is the pdf global variable declared, described in the link above.
In theory looks easy, but it doesn't work for me, as it says that the global pdf variable that they are talking about in the link is `undefined`.
What should I do? How to make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the pluging hasn't installed correctly. When I installed it once again, now everything is in order, and the pdf variable is not undefined any longer. So I didn't need to try to find out where it is declared, in order to search for problems.